# MSSQL/TSQL Joining against a subquery

Tags: sql-server, iis, sharepoint

I'm analyzing IIS log files from sharepoint and need to match each entry to it's SPWeb.

This SQL code works for a single value (@var1):

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(128);         
set @var1 = '/sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/marketing.docx';

select
    TOP 1 *,
    charindex(urlstub, @var1) as found 
from 
    spwebs
where
    charindex(urlstub, @var1)  = 1
order by
    urlstub DESC;
```

I'm looking for a way to get this to work for a tables worth of data instead of just the single variable @var1.

Example data

```
SPwebs:    
/sites/Site1
/sites/Site1/Subsite1
/sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2
/sites/Site2
etc..

IISlog: (this is the table I'd like to take the place of @var1 above) 
/sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/marketing.docx
/sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/sales.docx
/sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/hr.docx
/sites/Site1/research/funding.docx
```

The expected outcome of the above would be:
`Foreach` record in the `IISLog` table:
Find the best/deepest matching record from the `spwebs` table:

```
|table                                                    | matchingSPweb                   |
|---------------------------------------------------------| --------------------------------|
| /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/marketing.docx | /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/ |
| /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/sales.docx     | /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/  |
| /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/Documents/hr.docx        | /sites/Site1/Subsite1/Subsite2/  |
| /sites/Site1/research/funding.docx                      | /sites/Site1                     |
```

I've tried

```
select iislogs2.*, spwebs.urlstub
from 
iislogs2
inner join 
(   
  select TOP 1 urlstub, csURIStem as found 
  from spwebs
   where charindex(urlstub, iislogs2.csUriStem)  = 1
  order by urlstub DESC
)   as x
on x.csuristem = iislogs2.csUriStem
```

but this just errors, it doesn't seem to understand csUriStem in the context of the subselect statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest ways to fix your issue are either to change your current query to use a subquery in the select statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT iislogs2.*,
       urlstub = (SELECT TOP 1 urlstub FROM spwebs WHERE CHARINDEX(urlstub, iislogs2.csUriStem) = 1 ORDER BY urlstub DESC)
from iislogs2;
```

... or change your current join to a cross apply, e.g.:

```
SELECT iislogs2.*, x.urlstub
from iislogs2
cross apply (SELECT TOP 1 urlstub FROM spwebs WHERE CHARINDEX(urlstub, iislogs2.csUriStem) = 1 ORDER BY urlstub DESC) AS x;
```

**EDIT**:
The query optimiser might do all sorts of weird sorts and spools, so one option to avoid that might be to use an explicit join with a CTE and then left join this back to your original table. For example:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT i.csUriStem, s.urlstub, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.csUriStem ORDER BY s.urlstub DESC)
    FROM iislogs2 AS i
    JOIN spwebs AS s
        ON i.csUriStem LIKE s.urlstub + '%'
)
SELECT i.*, c.urlstub
FROM iislogs2 AS i
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c
    ON c.csUriStem = i.csUriStem
    AND c.RN = 1;
```

Unfortunately, with strings and substrings, it's hard to get an execution plan that is *really* optimal for what you want to do, but I expect  this sort of query will perform better with indexes than the other two.

Comment: Firstly, this is fantastic!

Comment: Secondly, It's _really_ slow, Processed about 6300 records in 45 minutes. I've indexed both columns. Any ideas on a  more efficient way to do this? 

(In real life, the spwebs table has about 5800 records, and iislogs2 will have millions of records)

I'm wondering if there's some way to load spwebs into memory (I assume it does already.

I'm also going to try scaling this up in azure to see if a higher tier would be faster.

Comment: Hm. It's hard to get the query optimiser to do what you want while using strings and substrings like this, but I'll edit in what I believe is probably your best option and you can give it a go and see how fast it runs.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on whether your columns allow nulls. I guess if my suggestion doesn't improve the performance, just play around with variations of `TOP 1`, `ROW_NUMBER()` and various ways of joining to make it faster. If, for example, the part inside the CTE runs fast but the part outside doesn't, you might even consider putting it into a temporary table, indexing that (comment, RN) and trying that instead of doing it all in one statement. Basically it comes down to playing with execution plans until you find one that does what you expect it to do.